# CkEditor use <b> tags instead <strong>

Tags: ckeditor

I use the newest version of CkEditor until now. I want, when I press "B" button, to put selected text between tags `<b>` and `</b>`, but not `<strong>...</strong>` as default. How to solve it?

Comment: Why do you want to use deprecated tags instead of standard tags?

Comment: becouse ~<strong>~ is not working in exists design. And I don`t want to change it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`config.coreStyles_bold`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-coreStyles_bold) option.

For example:

```
config.coreStyles_bold = { element: 'b', overrides: 'strong' };
```

Comment: it what place in the code it must be placed. I try it in 'config.js' file, but no results